# How should we handle edits to a question that only fix a few things?

Tags: discussion, edits

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56523554/react-native-cant-run-in-ios-by-command-but-it-can-run-in-xcode) is the one sample of the problem that I'm facing. Even if you are not familiar with the context of the question you can clearly see that the grammar is all over the place. I tried to go and edit the question only to find that it is already edited, I got curious to see who edited it and how such obvious mistakes went unnoticed and what exactly was edited?

Turned out the user who edited the question has editorial errors in his profile too, and he only changed a few words in title.

My question is how we can prevent things like this or improve these behaviors? Maybe timeout for the user? Maybe that user needs more than one reviewer?

Comment: Small cumulative improvements are fine on Stack Exchange.

Comment: The OP [accepted the suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/23230749), so I'm not sure there's a lot we can do about that.

Comment: The first edit should have been rejected. "code formated" is definitely not what the user did.

Comment: *"My question is how we can prevent things like this or improve these behaviors?"* not much; we don't curate people, only content. Once you have enough reputation points you can start to review suggested edits which has a rejection option. Until then... make good edits. Teach by example.

Comment: It appears to be that <2k users have to make complete edits but at >2k any small and minor edit improvement is fine. It's not something I particularly like or agree with but that's the way things happen around here in my experience.

Comment: @TheLethalCoder The reasoning for that, IIRC, has always been that <2k edits are suggestions that require 2 other users to spend their time reviewing the edit. Thus if you're going to make us spend our time reviewing something, it should be worthwhile.

Comment: @TylerH I understand the background argument to it but it's still not something I particularly agree with. Especially as these minimal edits send the message that they are fine and then new users end up with rejected edits for following the norm.

Comment: @TheLethalCoder Sure; I'm not necessarily arguing it's right, either. Just adding the reasoning there for anyone who may be wondering.